# Subsets having duplicates?

Tags: collections, language-agnostic, logic

Can a subset, not a proper subset, have duplicate values?

Example

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}
B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

is `AcB` or does the duplicate value cancel that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes little sense, but I'll try answering anyway.

> Can a subset, not a proper subset, have duplicate values?

No, a subset is a set, and sets do not have duplicate values.

> Example `A = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}` `B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
>
> is `AcB` or does the duplicate value cancel that out?

I'm not even sure if `A = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}` is valid notation, but yes, unless you're talking about [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), `A` is a subset of `B` in this case.